# How can I use Prisma types on a nest.js GraphQL query argument

Tags: graphql, nestjs, prisma

I'm working on a simple GraphQL query that allows me to fetch a list of users. I want to be able to sort them through my request. I'm using Prisma as an ORM.

As per the documentation, my service simply looks like this:

```
  /**
   * Find all users
   */
  findAll({
    skip,
    take,
    cursor,
    where,
    orderBy,
  }: {
    skip?: number;
    take?: number;
    cursor?: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput;
    where?: Prisma.UserWhereInput;
    orderBy?: Prisma.UserOrderByWithRelationInput;
  }) {
    return this.prisma.user.findMany({
      skip,
      take,
      cursor,
      where,
      orderBy,
    });
  }
```

Now, I'd like to add the arg to my query, so I went with this:

```
    @Args("orderBy", {
      defaultValue: { createdAt: "desc" },
      type: () => Prisma.UserOrderByWithRelationInput,
      nullable: true,
    })
```

But this raises an error, saying that `Property 'UserOrderByWithRelationInput' does not exist on type 'typeof Prisma'.`

How can I specify the type of this arg, using the generated Prisma types ?

Answer (score 0):

There are packages that generate classes from prisma schema, like `prisma-nestjs-graphql` which i've been using recently.

This is an example:

```js
// user.resolver.ts -----------------------------------

import { User, UserCreateInput } from 'src/@generated';

@Mutation(() => User, { nullable: true })
async createUser(
 @Args('data') data: UserCreateInput
) {
 return this.userService.createUser(data);
}

// user.service.ts ------------------------------------

async createUser(
 data: UserCreateInput,
): Promise<User> {
 return this.prisma.user.create({ data });
}
```

### Setup

This is my basic setup, there're more configurations, [see details](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma-nestjs-graphql)

`prisma.schema`

```
generator nestgraphql {
  provider                              = "node node_modules/prisma-nestjs-graphql"
  output                                = "../src/@generated"
  fields_Validator_from                 = "class-validator"
  fields_Validator_input                = true
  requireSingleFieldsInWhereUniqueInput = true
  emitSingle                            = true
  emitCompiled                          = true
  purgeOutput                           = true
  noTypeId                              = true
}
```

that's it! And run `npx prisma generate`, which generates classes in the defined path `/src/@generated/index.ts`

## Bonus!!!

**I also parse requested graphql schema to prisma select so tha only requested fields will be queried from db and also if your query has nested relations, you will not have to define separate resolve fields, otherwise you'll need to define resolve fields for every nested relations**

Example:

```js
// user.resolver.ts -----------------------------------

import PrismaSelect from 'src/decorators/prisma-select';
import { User, UserCreateInput } from 'src/@generated';

@Mutation(() => User, { nullable: true })
async createUser(
 @Args('data') data: UserCreateInput,
 @PrismaSelect() select: Prisma.UserSelect, // <----- here is the change
) {
 return this.userService.createUser(data, select);
}

// user.service.ts ------------------------------------

async createUser(
 data: UserCreateInput,
 select: Prisma.UserSelect // <----- here is the change
): Promise<User> {
 return this.prisma.user.create({ data, select });
}
```

```js
// src/decorators/prisma-select.ts

import { prismaSelect } from '@src/utils/prisma'

const PrismaSelect = createParamDecorator(
  (_data: any, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const gqlCtx = GqlExecutionContext.create(ctx);
    const info = gqlCtx.getInfo();
    
    return prismaSelect(info);
  },
);

export default PrismaSelect;
```

```js
// @src/utils/prisma.ts

import { GraphQLResolveInfo } from 'graphql';
import graphqlFields from 'graphql-fields';

export const prismaSelect = (
  info: GraphQLResolveInfo,
) => {
  const parsedFields = graphqlFields(info);

  const parse = (fields: any) => {
    let result: any = {};

    for (const key in fields) {
      if (key === '__typename') {
        delete fields[key];
        continue;
      }
      const value = fields[key];

      if (
        typeof value !== 'object' ||
        !Object.keys(value).length
      ) {
          result[key] = true;
      } else {
        result[key] = {
          select: parse(fields[key]),
        };
      }
    }

    return result;
  };

  return parse(parsedFields);
};
```

Lastly, put this prisma middleware which checks and removes nullable fields to prevent errors:

```js
// src/middlewares/index.ts

import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

export function PrismaExcludeNullableFieldsMiddleware<
  T extends Prisma.BatchPayload = Prisma.BatchPayload,
>(): Prisma.Middleware {
  return async (
    params: Prisma.MiddlewareParams,
    next: (params: Prisma.MiddlewareParams) => Promise<T>,
  ): Promise<T> => {
    const args = params.args || {};

    for (const key in args) {
      const nullable = !args[key] ?? !Object.keys(args[key]).length;
      if (nullable) delete args[key];
    }

    if (args?.select && !Object.keys(args.select).length) {
      args.select.id = true;
    }

    return next(params);
  };
}
```

I have simplified these last codes, if that i broke something, don't mind!, you generally get the point, you can fix, if you can't and you're still interested in this bonus part, i can share the full setup.